# can not match the text with the following pattern: @some words(optional):"sometext"+link(optional)

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern :

```
(with some words beginning with # or @)+"+sentence that does not contain any question+"
(with some words beginning with # or @) + "+sentence that does not contain any question+"+ with link 
 "+sentence that does not contain any question+"
```

So for example here are some matched texts with the pattern:

```
#cbc @RBC: "This is the video" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
"This is the video" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
  #cbc @RBC: "This is the video"
  "This is the video"
```

Here is my regular expression:

```
^(\\s[@|#]\\w+){0,}\".+\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+){0,}$
```

Here is my code:

```
private static void qoutedWrapped(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "^(\\s[@|#]\\w+){0,}\".+\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+){0,}$";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

But when I try it with :

```
@cbc: "I love u" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

it does not work

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language (Java?)

Comment: Also, fix the formatting. It's hard to tell which parts of the question are showing the pattern, and which are part of the question text.

Comment: You've been a member for 2 years, you should know by now how to format things in the SO editor.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for inconvenience I corrected it :)

Comment: @Barmar Thank u for ur advice but I think the problem is in regx part not in java part ;)

Comment: Different languages have different regular expression engines. And maybe you're wrong about where the problem is. You should use the appropriate tag to attract people who know the environment best.

Comment: BTW, the usual way to write `{0,}` is with `*`.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't allow a space between `"` and `http:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you need:

```
^(\\s*[@|#]\\w+)+:\".+\"([http|https]:\\/\\/\\S+)*$
```

And as mentioned use `*` instead of`{0,}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\\s[@|#]\w+){0,}\".+\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+){0,}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`(\\s[@|#]\\w+)` if to belive your "nonworking" example you are expecting white character to be the first character in the group

`@cbc: "why I love u?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` there is no required whitechar between `^` and `[@|#]` so it will no match. I dont know about rest of your regex but as you can see, it require carefull analisys.

Try using tools such 
https://www.debuggex.com/r/h8w0IB3SMkmEGYri or http://regexpal.com/ to test your regex on fly with multiple test inputs and regex explanation / visualisation. Also using `*` insteed `{0,}` feels more natural